# Why are email replies sent from iPhone not threaded in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email, iphone

I noticed that when replying to emails from my iPhone, they are no longer being grouped as a conversation in Gmail.

If I receive an email and reply via my iPhone email app, it will show up in my send folder on my desktop.  But not grouped in the conversation thread like it should.

Until recently, no matter where I replied from, the reply always ended up as a reply in the same conversation.

When I reply from my desktop, it does show properly as part of the conversation. Why?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is:  Is it me, or it is a problem in gmail or Apple?  If me, what can I do to fix it?

Since posting this yesterday, I've had other iPhone users tell me they're suddenly having the same problem.  So it seems that it's not just me but something on the blink in Apple or Gmail.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, there's something wrong with the iPhone 6, its configuration is not fully compatible with Exchange settings.